# Check value in dynamically changing nested JSON

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to get some JSONs using requests library. These JSONs always have status code 200 and normally look so:

```
{
   "response":{
      "count":2,
      "items":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "first_name":"Lorem",
            "last_name":"Ipsum",
            "is_closed":false,
            "can_access_closed":true,
            "track_code":"c8b0bA"
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "first_name":"Lorem",
            "last_name":"Ipsum",
            "is_closed":false,
            "can_access_closed":true,
            "track_code":"0776a72"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

But can be like:

```
{
   "error":{
      "error_code":6,
      "error_msg":"Too many requests per second",
      "request_params":[
         {
            "key":"count",
            "value":"10"
         },
         {
            "key":"",
            "value":""
         },
         {
            "key":"v",
            "value":"5.103"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

So I'm trying to request again JSONs that getting error. My current code:

```
for i in range(20):
    while True:
        r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events') #example
        json = r.json()
        if 'error_code' in json['error']:
            continue
        break
```

And I'm getting *KeyError: 'error'*. 
I also tried something like this:

```
for i in range(20):
    while True:
        r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events') #example
        json = r.json()
        if 'error_code' in json.get('error'):
            continue
        break
```

But got *TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `error` exists in json and then check the value for error_code:

```
if json.get('error') and 'error_code' in json.get('error'):
```

Alternately,

```
error_code = json.get('error', {}).get{'error_code')
if error_code:
  # take action
```

Comment: The pythonic way to test if a key is set in a dict is `if key in dict`. In the op's case, you can safely assume that you'll always get either "error" or "response" as root element, and that in the first case you'll always have "error_code" set, so it's not even needed to check for "error_code". IOW, Seleme's answer below is the right answer. Yours would be correct if some other cases though...

Comment: The assumption that you'll always have "error_code" set, if "error" appears in json is largely dependent on the server and unless the client handles it effectively, the client code can result in an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Since `json.get('error')` **can** give you `None` in case `error` is not inside `json`, then it is understandable that you get this error. Why don't you do the following:

```
if 'error' in json:
    # code
```

Also, you should not do `while True` requests in case of `Too many requests`. Sleep or at least do exponential backoff in between your requests.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```py
import json #change over here

for i in range(20):
    while True:
        r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events') #example
        json = json.loads(r)
        if 'error_code' in json['error']:
            continue
        break
```